# Get result length of Array.prototype.some()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a conditional which is checked via `Array.prototype.some()`. Considering this array:

```js
const coolArray = [
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: true }
]

const isCool = coolArray.some(item => item.isCool === true)

if (isCool) {
  console.log("hello I'm cool!")
}
```

However, I wanted that the check to happen when `item.isCool` is `true` **and** at least two items in the array match the condition. So the example above would not output the message, as there is only one `true` condition.

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Syntax) the reference for this method is `arr.some(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])`. However `[, array]` reference the original array instead of their clone, so doing the below outputs the same result:

```
const isCool = coolArray.some((item, index, arr) => {
  return item.isCool === true && arr.length > 1
})
```

I'm aware I could avoid `.some()` and iterate over the array using `map` or `for` and save in an external array the results so I could check the length, something similar to:

```
const isCoolArr = []
coolArray.map(item => item.isCool ? isCoolArr.push(item) : false)
console.log('expected result:', isCoolArr.length) // outputs 1
```

But I'm not particularly happy with this method and looking for simpler alternatives. Can `.some()` fit what I need or do I need another alternative? Are there any, other than the case I mentioned above?

Comment: `coolArray.filter(item => item.isCool).length >= 2`

Comment: @p.s.w.g `atleast two` so it should `>= 2` or `> 1`

Answer (score 2):

With `.filter()`, you lose the short-circuiting benefit that you get with `.some()`. One option would be to use a variable external to the callback.

```js
const coolArray = [{isCool: false},{isCool: false},{isCool: true}]
let count = 0

const isCool = coolArray.some(item => (count += item.isCool) >= 2)

if (isCool) {
  console.log("hello I'm cool!")
} else {
  console.log("not cool enough")
}
```

This takes advantage of conversion of booleans into numbers. If you don't like that, you can be more explicit.

```js
const coolArray = [{isCool: false},{isCool: false},{isCool: true}]
let count = 0

const isCool = coolArray.some(item => item.isCool && ++count >= 2)

if (isCool) {
  console.log("hello I'm cool!")
} else {
  console.log("not cool enough")
}
```

Or make it without adding an extra variable!

```js
const coolArray = [{isCool: false},{isCool: false},{isCool: true}]
let isCool = 0;

isCool = coolArray.some(item => item.isCool && ++isCool >= 2);

if (isCool) {
  console.log("hello I'm cool!")
} else {
  console.log("not cool enough")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array.reduce

```
const coolArray = [
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: true }
]

const count = coolArray.reduce((accum, item) => Number(item.isCool) + accum, 0)

if (count >= 2) {
  console.log("Hello I'm cool!")
}
```

Comment: Using post-increment would not work, this way it does :)

Comment: coolArray.reduce((accum, item) => Number(item.isCool) + accum, 0)  Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and than check length

```js
const coolArray = [
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: true }
]

const isCool = coolArray.filter(item => item.isCool === true)

if (isCool.length > 1 ) {
  console.log("hello I'm cool!")
} else{
  console.log('length is less than 2')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people suggested to use `filter` and check `length`. I would like create a method atLeast which would break if the condition is met

```js
const coolArray = [
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: false },
  { isCool: true }
]

function x(cb,num){
  let count = 0;
  for(let i =0;i<this.length;i++){
    if(cb(this[i],i,this)) count++;
    if(count === num) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'atLeast',{
  value:x,
  writeable:true
})

console.log(coolArray.atLeast(x => x.isCool === true,1)); //true
console.log(coolArray.atLeast(x => x.isCool === true,2)); //false
```

Comment: I'd always use `defineProperty` when changing the prototype, to avoid side effects.

Comment: @JonasWilms I have edited the code. I would like to know those side effects.

Comment: `for(let key in []) console.log(key);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple generic implementation that stops once the limit is reached:

```js
let someTimes = (array, fn, count) => array.some(x => !(count -= Boolean(fn(x))));

console.log(someTimes(
    [1,2,3,44,5,66,7,99],
    x => x > 10,
    2
))
```

or, perhaps even nicer,

```js
let countDown = (fn, count) => x => !(count -= !!fn(x));


console.log(
    [1, 2, 3, 44, 5, 66, 7, 99].some(countDown(x => x > 10, 2))
)
```

In most cases the early exit optimization isn't worth the trouble though, and you can simply use much more useful generic counter function:

```js
let countWhere = (array, fn) => array.reduce((n, x) => n + Boolean(fn(x)), 0);

console.log(countWhere(
    [1,2,3,44,5,66,7,99],
    x => x > 10
) >= 2)
```